# Why `std::array` doesn't offer bit packing for boolean values like what `std::vector` does?

Tags: c++, stdarray

As far as I know `std::array` doesn't pack bits for boolean values like `bitset` but `std::vector` does, but I cannot find any explanation for this online.

Why did the C++ developers decide not to do this?

Comment: The packing of `std::vector<bool>` is mostly seen as design mistake. (it requires wrapper, and induces lot of exception `for(bool& b : v)` is wrong for example).

Comment: Questions about why other people did something are best answered *by those people*, or at least, by things that they wrote. Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum and we are not telepathic.

Comment: Well, what if the programmer actually wanted a container of `bool`?  What would they choose?  The designers decided to let sleeping dogs lie and only have `std::vector<bool>` be special.

Comment: Food for thought: what functionality from `std::array<bool,N>` would you give up by using `std::bitset<N>` instead? (There is some, but think about it.) Both represent a fixed-size sequence of yes-no values. If `std::vector<bool>` was not specialized, how would you get a space-optimized dynamically-sized sequence of yes-no values?

Comment: `std::array` imitates a C-style array with stronger semantic guarantees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q: Why does `std::vector` pack bits?
A: Poor design.

Q: Why doesn't `std::array` pack bits?
A: Learned from the previous mistake.